# Any way to make QGIS display band names of a stack properly?

Tags: qgis, raster, band

I'm working with several layer stacks that have 100+ bands in QGIS.
The stacks are ENVI files, all band names are properly stored in the headers. Unfortunately, QGIS will not diplay them when choosing the style or when extracting info by clicking on the map. However, QGIS will show all the names Properties->Metadata.

Isn't there any way to get the band names to show properly?